# How do I install Windows alonside Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: system-installation

I quit using Microsoft software years ago, but need to be able to also run Windows software occasionally (car navigation device software, phone sync software, etc.) How do I go about it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and run Windows as a VM.

The [VM Player](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/6_0) is also a good solution for running Windows within Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

What do you exactly mean by 'Alongside'?

**1.If you want to do a dualboot**

.Create a bootable USB stick and install windows.It'll show the options of ubuntu and windows at the time of booting.
To create a bootable USB following link can be helpful:

[Create Bootable USB Of windows on Linux](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/create-bootable-windows-7-usb-drive.html)

**2.If you want to use Windows on Virtual Machine**

1.Use VirtualBox/VM Player and create and install windows in virtual HDD.

Comment: if you decide to use a dualboot i suggest you: first install windows, then linux (ubuntu) - it's more easy to handle the dualboot with grub.
with a dualboot you need to reboot your system every time you want to switch between linux and windows...
a virtual machine is more practicable if you don't plan to do somethink like gaming etc. on the virual machine (note: the hardware of it is just emulated...) - but to do something with your car navigation software and run iTunes or something like that a virual machine will satisfy your needs!